# Azure Function - 'AzureWebJobsServiceBusConnectionString' is missing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

**Use Case:**

I've an Azure Function that will be triggered by 'serviceBusTrigger'.  Following best practices, I've the Azure service bus connection string in 'appsettings.json' and likewise in app-settings on the Azure function app.  All is well!

Now, I want to run the function locally and I am using cli like

> cd "my function folder path"
>
> func run .\myfunction.cs

**Issue**

It starts but gives an error

'*Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.someFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsServiceBusConnectionString' is missing or empty.*'

**Questions**

1) Is is possible to keep my setup and be able to launch the function via 'cli'
2) how do i resolve this error
side note:  I understand that Azure function is build on top of webJob SDK and this error is bit cryptic.

Attached image shows the setup for function, function.json, appsettings.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYALv.png)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm noticing a couple of issues with the image you've shared:

Connection strings would typically go in the connection strings object of your app settings file, for example:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "appsetting1": "test"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeConnectionString": "connectionstring"
  }
}
```

The `function.json`is invalid. Your bindings should be an array, like:

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
             ... ....
            "connection": "ConnectionName"
             ... ....
        }
    ]
}
```

You cannot just point to a `cs` file to run the function.
You're still expected to have the following structure when running your function:

```
 root
  |
  +-- functionname
  |   |-- function.json
  |   \-- run.csx (if working with the CSX model/just code)
  |
  +-- host.json
  +-- local.settings.json
```

From the root, you can then invoke the function using `func run <functionname>` where functionname maps to the folder name.

The file name shouldn't be an issue, but rename it to `local.settings.json` as it has changed.

You may also want to take a look at the [Azure Functions Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/), as the will take care of all the setup for you and still allow you to run from the command like with the created structured, using the CLI, if you wish.

Comment: Fabio, thank you for quick response.  Running it from the root folder solved the issue (the settings got picked up correctly).   My local bindings are an array; however, when forming an example (in the screenshot) I missed the array brackets.

Comment: I had a feeling that was an issue with what you shared and not what you had setup. Just wanted to call it out, just in case. Glad to hear this is now working.